# Countable Ultrahomogeneous Structures

Tags: logic, model-theory

I've been learning about countable ultrahomogeneous structures, where ultrahomogeneous means every isomorphism of finitely generated substructures extends to an automorphism of the whole structure.  For instance, $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ is the unique countable ultrahomogeneous linear order.

For linear orders, it is nice to have an easy to understand instantiation of the ultrahomogeneous structure instead of an amorphous highly-uniform linear order.  In trying to understand the countable ultrahomogenous graphs and boolean algebras, I was hoping to find some good constructions to help see what these are like, rather than a random/generic structure or a universal one (like being a Fraisse Limit of a class of finite structures).

So, anything to help me get a grasp of these (or other) ultrahomogeneous structures would be appreciated.

Comment: Two references: *Homogeneous partially ordered sets*, by Alan Mekler, in [**Finite and Infinite Combinatorics in Sets and Logic**](http://books.google.com/books?id=g7HGp3FhYtsC). And [*Classification of some homogeneous and ultrahomogeneous structures*](http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~adevil/doc/theseCORR.pdf), by Alice Devillers.